# Javascript recursive search

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm having some trouble with a recursive search. I want to return the block the ID was found in.

This is my data:

```
{
"rows": [{
    "columns": [{
        "id": "iE1YMSahu",
        "rows": [{
            "columns": [{
                "id": "VJBjVrfP"
            }, {
                "id": "NJb1234A",
                "rows": [{
                    "columns": [{
                        "id": "VJBjVXXX"
                    }, {
                        "id": "NJb1234B"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "EJnASD-v",
        "rows": [{
            "columns": [{
                "id": "VJBjVYYY"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

It should be returning

```
    {
        "id": "EJnASD-v",
        "rows": [{
            "columns": [{
                "id": "VJBjVYYY"
            }]
        }]
    }
```

But instead it's returning false. Here's my code:

```
function findColumnWithId(obj, id){
    for(var i = 0; i < obj['rows'].length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < obj['rows'][i]['columns'].length; j++){
            if(obj['rows'][i]['columns'][j].id == id)
                return obj;

            if(obj['rows'][i]['columns'][j].hasOwnProperty('rows')){
                var result = findColumnWithId(obj['rows'][i]['columns'][j], id);

                if(typeof result !== false)
                    return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

findColumnWithId(data, 'VJBjVYYY');
```

I'm really not sure what's going on. It doesn't seem to be iterating over the last part of the Json data. This code actually does work in 5 out of my 6 use cases, which makes it even more strange.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you writing `typeof result !== false`? What’s that supposed to do?

Comment: Welp, I feel stupid now. Removing typeof fixed my code (of course). I changed it from `typeof result !== 'undefined` to a check for false and forgot to remove the typeof. Thanks.

Comment: aren't you missing an id in the first row object?

Answer (score 1):

Removing 'typeof' in this if statement fixes my code.

```
if(typeof result !== false)
```